# How to open Maps app from my code to show directions?

Tags: iphone

HI.. I have to show directions between two coordinates. I'd like to open Maps app, passing the start and end coordinates from my code.

I don't want to open it in the Google maps, which opens in browser(Safari). I tried that method. That was working perfect.

```
NSString* urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", s_lat, s_long, d_lat, d_long];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

But, I want to open iPhone Maps app. How can i do this? Is this possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it on a real device. I'm using the same code and it opens Safari at the simulator and iPhone Maps at the device.

Comment: Oh.. My God.. I didn't even test my app in device before asking question. Forgive my foolishness. Thank you so much for your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Hey Simon the method you are using is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

will only open safari.So there is no chance that with open url you would open a diiferent thing.You can use the UIWebView for this and then load the webview with the url.I think that would be the simple thing like this

```
 views=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [views setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    NSString* urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", s_lat, s_long, d_lat, d_long];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //[views loadHTMLString:googlePage baseURL:requestURL];
    [views loadRequest:req];
    self.view=views;
```

And if you even don't want to use this then then you can use the MapKit provided in your XCode Frameworks.Hope this would help you.